How difficult would it be to earn a Computer Engineering MSc as someone with a Physics MSc?
I have a Physics MSc (and physics BSc with a math minor), and I'm considering if I should pursue a second MSc in computer engineering. This would prepare me all the better for a career working in quantum computing. I'm particularly interested in architecture design in optimizing for specific quantum algorithms, and dynamic reconfiguration.
I have a hobbyist level knowledge of computer hardware (having built one some years back, and running a basic homelab with an RPi and a NAS today) and a basic familiarity with some high level languages (e.g. Python, Wolfram, LaTeX, LUA, etc.). Other than that though, the only "formal" background I have in computer engineering is an IBM certification on the fundamentals of quantum information. Of course, I also learned basic circuitry as an undergrad, and have since taught labs for that as a graduate TA and adjunct lecturer.
Is going from where I am into a computer engineering MSc program realistic, or would the lack of knowledge from undergraduate courses specific to this field be too much of a hindrance to my success? I'm not opposed to some independent learning, but there are limits to what I'm able to do entirely on my own, and I'd very much want to do this ASAP if realistic.

TL;DR: Is an undergraduate education in computer engineering necessary before approaching graduate schooling in it if the person in question already has a strong foundation in mathematics and physics?

You might have more success posting this on another SE site like Computer Science. It seems off topic here.

Or a discussion site.  Although, in general, if you have a Master's degree in A, and you want a Master's in B, then no matter what A and B are, there is some school out there that will teach you the intervening steps to get you from A to B.  It's just a question of how long it'll take, and how much it'll cost.

Just ask them.  Every graduate school has an admissions officer,  Every MSc program has a list of pre-requisites.  They aren't all the same: some CE MSc programs are for new CE graduates: some are for lawyers or music majors.
